# After Triggers in sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, maintenance-plan

I have created two triggers. One on sysssispackages and another on sysjobs. thse two triggers will simply send a mail whenever anyone modifies a maintenance plan or a job(sans job schedule).

My problem is whenever someone modifies a MP, i get alerts for both the triggers(1 for sysssispackage and 2-4 alerts for sysjobs table). 
Is there any way by which I can restirct these alerts to the following cases.

1. If change is done from MP, I get alert for only sysssispackage table i.e 1 alert only.
2. If change is done on Jobs, I get alert only for sysjobs table.

One workaround is to alter the trigger on sysjobs table such that it checks in mail queue and sends mail accordingly.

But, I want to know if there is some other way for this.

Thanks.

P.S- My basic requirement is tracking who made changes in MP and Jobs.

Comment: Add the two triggers in question

Comment: I think your workaround is the best way to go.  Each trigger should check the mail queue/history, and if a mail hasn't been created already, add the message to the queue.   Or if you want, you can program the MP trigger to over-write the Job email if it hasn't already been sent.